# "global" keyword needed in the top-level declaration

Tags: python, global-variables

I am keen to know whether there is any need to use the keyword `global` in the top-level declaration/assignment in Python (such as the one for the 1st line of code below).

Both `fn_2()` and `fn_4()` have the same effect to change the corresponding variables in the codes below.

```
global factor_1
factor_1 = None

factor_2 = None

def main():

    print('factor_1 = {}, factor_2 = {}'.format(factor_1, factor_2))

    fn_1()
    print('factor_1 = {}, factor_2 = {}'.format(factor_1, factor_2))

    fn_2()
    print('factor_1 = {}, factor_2 = {}'.format(factor_1, factor_2))

    fn_3()
    print('factor_1 = {}, factor_2 = {}'.format(factor_1, factor_2))

    fn_4()
    print('factor_1 = {}, factor_2 = {}'.format(factor_1, factor_2))

def fn_1():
    factor_1 = 10

def fn_2():
    global factor_1
    factor_1 = 20

def fn_3():
    factor_2 = 30

def fn_4():
    global factor_2
    factor_2 = 40

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `global` is redundant inside the global scope.

Comment: I wish `global` was a syntax error at global scope, with a nice helpful error message telling you what you're doing wrong instead of just silently doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.  You need to use `global` inside a function if you want to set the value of a global variable in that function.  You don't need to use `global` outside functions.

Answer (score 0):

`global` allows you to use a variable that is outside the scope of a function, so it must be used inside of a function:

```
def fn_1():
    # this is declaring a local variable factor_1
    factor_1 = 10

def fn_2():
    # this is changing the value of the global variable factor_1
    global factor_1
    factor_1 = 20

def fn_3():
    # this is declaring a local variable factor_2
    factor_2 = 30

def fn_4():
    # this is changing the value of the global variable factor_2
    global factor_2
    factor_2 = 40
```